# Handle missing reference to COM interface (MATLAB) nicely

Tags: c#, matlab

I have a VS2013 C# project which references the MATLAB COM interface. 90% of what the app does is in no way related to MATLAB and I would like to be able to compile and run in environments where MATLAB is not available. The desired behavior is:

- Build, regardless of presence of the reference (throwing a warning).
- If MATLAB is not available, print a message if the user tries to execute MATLAB specific functionality, but it should not be fatal.

My first instinct was to use a pre-processor directive with different build configurations, but I would like to avoid this because it gets messy when setting up continuous integration and tests etc.

So I tried some reflection:

```
try
{
  var matlab = Activator.CreateComInstanceFrom("appname.exe", "MLApp.MLApp").Unwrap();
}
catch
{
  //message
}
```

Which throws a MissingMethodException (i.e. it cannot find a constructor).  When MATLAB is present this works fine:

```
     var matlab = new MLApp.MLApp();
```

New ideas most welcome, thanks in advance!

**Edit:**
See below for a detailed answer, but for those looking for a quick bit of test code, here is what worked for me.

```
        var Matlab_t = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Matlab.Autoserver");

        if (Matlab_t != null)
            matlab = Activator.CreateInstance(Matlab_t);
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Matlab installation not found.\n");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my COM related Unit Tests / Detectors I simply do it in multiple steps:

1. Find COM type
2. Create COM object from type
3. Call methods.
4. Release COM objects, all of them.

In your case I would suggest writing mapper class hiding all of this COM ugliness under layer of abstraction. (I just needed those helpers to test COM library I wrote, so it was opposite)

[Type.GetTypeFromProgID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hss5hw09(v=vs.110).aspx) throws no exceptions when type is not found, instead it simply returns `null`.

```
    public static object GetComObject(string typeName)
    {
        Type ComType;

        ComType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID(typeName);
        if (ComType == null)
        {
            //COM type not found
        }
        // Create an instance of your COM Registered Object.
        return Activator.CreateInstance(ComType);
    }
```

When object is (or is not) created I follow up with `dynamic` or hand-written reflections (does same stuff as dynamic but with higher degree of control, and also works in older .NET versions).

```
    public static object CallFunction(string method, string typeName, params object[] args)
    {
        Type ComType;
        object ComObject;

        ComType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID(typeName);
        if (ComType == null)
        {
            //COM type not found
        }

        // Create an instance of your COM Registered Object.
        ComObject = Activator.CreateInstance(ComType);

        // Call the Method and cast return to whatever it should be.
        return ComType.InvokeMember(method, BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, ComObject, args);
    }
```

After work is finished you should release them, all of them. Including objects returned by (created by) methods in root COM object. (Releasing parent, but not its children causes, aside of memleaks, Unit Test engine to freeze, nasty)

```
    public static void DisposeCOM(dynamic obj)
    {
        if (obj != null)
        {
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks!  Very good suggestions as well. I have now encapsulated the ugliness in a mapper class as well.  The key to the fix was using Type.GetTypeFromProgID and the generic CreateInstance method instead of CreateComInstanceFrom.

Comment: @user102569 just don't forget to dispose objects. I think that `using` mapper with [Dispose Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.110).aspx) would fit here well (COM object is native resource after all).